# A Quick Way to Find the Volume of a Dodecahedron from Surface Area

Tags: volume

The surface area of one dodecahedron is 9. A similar dodecahedron has a surface area of 16. What is the ratio of the volume of the first dodecahedron to the second?

I need a quick way to solve this, like for a math competition

Comment: https://www.tes.com/teaching-resource/ratio-of-length-area-and-volume-of-similar-shapes-6336751

Answer (score 0):

You do not need such a formula. Instead, analyze the scaling; surface area grows with the square and volume with the cube.

Comment: More information please... I do not understand